# Query to return dynamic number of rows using SQL in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a unique requirement to return number of result rows in multiples of 10. Example, if actual data rows are 3, I must add another 7 blank rows to make it 10. If actual data rows are 16, I must add another 4 blank rows to make it 20, and so on.

Without using a procedure, is it possible to achieve this using SELECT statement?
The blank rows can simply contain NULL values or spaces or zeroes.

You can assume any simple query for data rows; the objective is to understand how to return rows dynamically in multiples of 10.

Example:

```
Select EmpName FROM Employees
```

If there are 3 employees, I should still return 10 rows, with the balance 7 rows containing either NULL value or blanks.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: So, you want the count of rows, rounded up to the nearest 10?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: `SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*)  + 9) / 10) * 10 FROM TABLE;` would give you the count

Comment: @Manav, I dont want the count of rows. I want the actual no. of rows to be returned as the next multiple of 10.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have edited the question. I had already explained that the actual query is irrelevant here, it can be any query. The objective is to understand how to add rows so that the number of rows returned is a next higher multiple of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above 2 answers, here is what I did:

```
WITH DATA AS
(SELECT EmpName FROM Employees),
DataSummary AS
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumDataRows FROM DATA),
ReqdDataRows AS
(SELECT CEILING(NumDataRows/10.0)*10 AS NumRowsReqd FROM DataSummary),
FillerRows AS 
(
SELECT 1 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 8 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 9 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS SLNO, '00000' AS FillerCol
)
SELECT * FROM DATA
--UNION ALL
--SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NumDataRows) FROM DataSummary
--UNION ALL
--SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NumRowsReqd) FROM ReqdDataRows
UNION ALL
SELECT FillerCol FROM FillerRows
WHERE (SELECT NumDataRows FROM DataSummary) + SLNO <= (SELECT NumRowsReqd FROM ReqdDataRows)
```

This gives me the output what I want. This avoids use of `ROW_NUMBER` and `ORDER`ing. The table FillerRows can be further simplified using `SELECT * FROM (VALUES...)`, and the 2nd and 3rd table `DataSummary` and `ReqdDataRows` can be merged into a single SELECT statement.

This approach is a step by step approach and easy to understand and debug, like:

1. Get the actual data rows
2. Get count of the data rows
3. Calculate required no. data rows
4. UNION the actual data rows with filler rows

Any suggestions on further simplifying this are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is very raw idea how it can be achieved:

```
WITH data(r) AS (
   SELECT 1 r FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r+1 r FROM data WHERE r < 10
  ) 
SELECT sd.* 
FROM data d
left join some_data sd on d.r = sd.id
```

This is dual table structure:

```
create table dual (dummy varchar(1));
insert into dual values ('x');
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ffcc/4

One of the possible options is this:

```
WITH data(r) AS (
   SELECT 1 r FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r+1 r FROM data WHERE r < 10
  ) 
SELECT sd.* 
FROM 
(select r, row_number() over (order by r) rn from data) d
left join ( 
   select id, name, row_number() over (order by id) rn from some_data sd
) sd 
on d.rn = sd.rn
```

The obvious disadvantages of this colutions:

- 'r' value generation rule most probably is not as simple in your
  case.
- Number of rows must be known before query execution.

But maybe it will help you to find better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, fairly easy, way to handle it...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    EmpID INT NOT NULL,
    EmpName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );
INSERT #TestData(EmpID, EmpName) VALUES
    (47, 'Bob'),(33, 'Mary'), (88, 'Sue');

-- data as it exists...
SELECT 
    td.EmpID, 
    td.EmpName
FROM
    #TestData td;

-- the desired output...
WITH
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            td.EmpID, 
            td.EmpName,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY td.EmpName)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        ),
    cte_TenRows AS (
        SELECT n.RN FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) ) n (RN)
        )
SELECT 
    ar.EmpID,
    ar.EmpName
FROM
    cte_TenRows tr
    LEFT JOIN cte_AddRN ar
        ON tr.RN = ar.RN
ORDER BY
    tr.RN;
```

Results...

```
-- data as it exists...
EmpID       EmpName
----------- --------------------
47          Bob
33          Mary
88          Sue


-- the desired output...
EmpID       EmpName
----------- --------------------
47          Bob
33          Mary
88          Sue
NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL
```